# <li> elements can't have Javascript Events bound to them when displayed by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-lists, event-listener

Ok, I have a drop down menu displayed through a UL and LI's tags. It is rendered through a php script that echos:

```
'<li id='. $value .'>'.$value.'</li>'
```

The Jquery function below works for the LI elements displayed this way.
The list changes dynamically through another ajax php script. The ajax echos the EXACT same thing (copy and pasted). It displays perfectly, however the Jquery function/Event Listener no longer applies to the LI elements.

Why is this??? Thanks in advance.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    //anything
    alert('works');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('li').click` only affects elements that are already on the page. Try something like this:

```
$('ol,ul').on('click','li',function() {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said list changes dynamically you might need event delegation using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for jquery >=1.7 and live for earlier versions. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li' , function() { // Change document to ul or any other container that exists in DOM at any time to have the event delegated to li's
    //anything
    alert('works');
}
```

What proabably is happening in your case is that when you bind the click event they are bound only to the li's that are present in DOM at that time. But later you update/add li's dynamically through AJAX calls, regular event binding directly on li's won't get applied on this. So you just bind the event to *another container(like ul or any other that exists in DOM at any time) or to the `document` head* so that the li's present now or created in the future gets the click event available by delegation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function() {
    //anything
    alert('works');
}
```

Click only works for items already on the page.

Use "on" if content is added after the handler is wired up

```
$('ul').on('click','li',function() {
    //anything
    alert('works');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set up click handlers for those `<li>` that exist when you run it. If you add more later, they won't automatically have the click handler attached.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    //anything
    alert('works');
}
```

Starting from this:

```
<ul id=container>
  <li>Option 1</li>
</div>
```

You can use Query's `.on` method to delegate the click handler from your `<ul>` element

```
$('#container').on('click','li', function() {
   // do your stuff here. **this** points to the clicked <li>
});
```

Any `<li>` elements added to the `<ul>` will automatically get the click handler functionality.